# Batch Exporting to CSV

Tags: c#, sql-server, csv, ado.net

I am processesing a large number of appointments to csv sending notifications out to users etc. What I want to do is set a `isProcessed` flag to say that the current line has already been processed I not sure how to do that in my current loop.

```
public void DumpTableToFile(SqlConnection connection, string tableName, string destinationFile)
    {
        using (var command = new SqlCommand("select LineType,CustomerFirstName AS 'Forename' ,CustomerLastName,Age,dob as 'Date of Birth',maritalStatus AS 'Marital Status',homePhone AS 'Home', mobileNumber AS Mobile,emailAddress AS Email,Address1 + Address2  + PostCode AS 'Address' ,employmentStatus AS Employment,occupation AS Occupation,propertyValue AS 'Property Value',mortgageBalance AS 'Mortgage Balance',balanceOnSecuredDebt AS 'Balance on secured Debt',mortgageType as 'Mortgage Type' from " + tableName, connection))
        using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        using (var outFile = File.CreateText(destinationFile))
        {
            string[] columnNames = GetColumnNames(reader).ToArray();
            int numFields = columnNames.Length;
            outFile.WriteLine(string.Join(",", columnNames));
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    string[] columnValues =
                        Enumerable.Range(0, numFields)
                                  .Select(i => reader.GetValue(i).ToString())
                                  .Select(field => string.Concat("\"", field.Replace("\"", "\"\""), "\""))
                                  .ToArray();

                    outFile.WriteLine(string.Join(",", columnValues));
                }
            }
        }
```

The flag is called isProcessed and I want to set it to `true` once its gone through the csv export. This is so I can do batching export. It exists within the same table appointments

**Edit 1**

Sorry for not stating I am wanting this flag to be written back to the appointments table for the curent record it is spitting out in the csv export the csv export works I just need a way of identifying that its been exported so its not processed a second time.

Comment: What do you want this flag to do? Is it supposed to be part of the file you write out? An in-memory status?

Comment: @EricJ. made an edit there to explain myself please see edit 1

Comment: Thanks very much for the vote up there apreciated that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the follow steps:

1. Add a criterium to your query: `WHERE NOT isProcessed`, so next the you do an export, only the records that are not processed will be processed.
2. After finishing your export, send this command to the database:`"UPDATE " + tableName + " SET isProcessed=true WHERE <exact same criteria as the select statement>"`. This way all records are now marked as processed.
3. Wrap a TransactionScope arround export-mechanisme incl. the update. This way, when something fails, the whole operation will be rolled back.
4. Wrap a try-catch arround the `TransactionScope`, so when the export fails, the CSV-file is deleted, so you will never have a half exported batch.

Your code would become something like this (I did not test it):

```
public void DumpTableToFile(SqlConnection connection, string tableName, string destinationFile)
{
    try
    {
        using(var transaction = new TransactionScope())
        {
            // Select all non-processed records.
            using (var command = new SqlCommand("select LineType,CustomerFirstName AS 'Forename' ,CustomerLastName,Age,dob as 'Date of Birth',maritalStatus AS 'Marital Status',homePhone AS 'Home', mobileNumber AS Mobile,emailAddress AS Email,Address1 + Address2  + PostCode AS 'Address' ,employmentStatus AS Employment,occupation AS Occupation,propertyValue AS 'Property Value',mortgageBalance AS 'Mortgage Balance',balanceOnSecuredDebt AS 'Balance on secured Debt',mortgageType as 'Mortgage Type' from " + tableName 
                + " WHERE NOT isProcessed", connection))
            using(var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            using(var outFile = File.CreateText(destinationFile))
            {
                string[] columnNames = GetColumnNames(reader).ToArray();
                int numFields = columnNames.Length;
                outFile.WriteLine(string.Join(",", columnNames));
                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    while(reader.Read())
                    {
                        string[] columnValues =
                            Enumerable.Range(0, numFields)
                                .Select(i => reader.GetValue(i).ToString())
                                .Select(field => string.Concat("\"", field.Replace("\"", "\"\""), "\""))
                                .ToArray();

                        outFile.WriteLine(string.Join(",", columnValues));
                    }
                }
            }

            // Update the same records that were just exported.
            using (var command = new SqlCommand("UPDATE " + tableName + " SET isProcessed=true WHERE NOT isProcessed", connection))
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            transaction.Complete();
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        // If something went wrong, delete the export file.
        File.Delete(destinationFile);
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: hi where does the TransactionScope come from ? its not resolving for me at all

Comment: You have make a reference to System.Transactions.dll.

Comment: This is a good answer but vulnerable to SQL injection attacks if a user is ever able to influence the contents of `tableName` (as is the OP's code). @david please ensure that is not possible. When constructing a query with user input be sure and use parameterized queries.

Comment: @EricJ. this is only being run on a console app so that does not really apply or does it ?.

Comment: Console apps *can* get input from the user directly or from configuration files under the user's control. Just make sure that there is no possibility for a malicious user to influence what is in your variable `tableName`.

Comment: @EricJ.: You are absolutely right! In my answer I only focused on his question / problem. Other problems like SQL-injections was out of scope.

Comment: @MartinMulder: SQL injection can be a huge problem. Any time I see code that is vulnerable to it, I make it a point to educate the OP of the problem. Many beginners aren't aware of the issue and learn by copying bad examples. Even if you don't rewrite their code to be injection safe, I would recommend a sentence or two telling them what the issue is and suggesting they read up on how to prevent it.